# Scala worksheet is not displaying output in Intellij Community 2020.1

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am very new to scala and Intellij.
I installed intellij community edition 2020.1 on
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS using snap.
I have sbt 1.3.13, Scala 2.13.3, and JDK 1.8.
Somwhow scala worksheet is not producing any output on the right pane.
I spent time doing google etc. made sure I opened a scala sbt project.
Attaching screenshot.
Any idea, or pointer to try.
Thanks for your patience.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Singleton object are created [lazily](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html)

> An object is a class that has exactly one instance. It is created
> lazily when it is referenced, like a lazy val.

so you have to actually call the object after creating it like so

```
object simple_test {
  val s = 4
  println(s)
}
simple_test
```

This should now output something like

```
4 res0: simple_test.type = simple_test$@3e32d495
```

This is similar to what happens in the following snippet

```
lazy val x = {
  val s = 4
  println(s)
}
x
```